# downloading hydra with brew error (You must `brew link makedepend` before hydra can be installed)

Tags: shell, homebrew, sudo, hydra

I am trying to download Hydra in Terminal with Homebrew on my imac but it gives me this error:

```
You must `brew link makedepend` before hydra can be installed
```

And when I run:

```
brew link makedepend
```

It says:

```
Error: Could not symlink .
/usr/local/opt is not writable.
```

And if i use sudo it says:

```
Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.
As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all
build scripts full access to your system.
```

Can someone help me thank you!

Comment: `brew doctor` is your friend.

Comment: i think i tried using that how do you do that.??

Comment: See my answer .

Answer (score 0):

Run `brew update` first, and then `brew doctor`. It will likely ask you to use `chmod` on `/usr/local/`. Follow its instructions.